# How do I reproduce YouTube's "Show More" functionality?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, youtube

I want to reproduce YouTube's "Show More" functionality on my site. Below each video, there's a "Show More" link. If you click on that link, it moves down, and some previously-hidden text is shown. How can I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: You say you've Googled a lot, but the first result is still http://www.cssnewbie.com/showhide-content-css-javascript/ (for "javascript show more")

Comment: Given the state of the original text, language may be a barrier when Googling.

Comment: Abhi, please review how I've rewritten your question. We like brevity on Stack Overflow - ask a specific question, and try to avoid salutation and general commentary. You'll have better luck here if you follow that model.

Comment: A click handler that sets CSS display to "block"/"none" (or `show()`/`hide()` in jQuery). Basic stuff. Read a tutorial on JavaScript event handlers.

Comment: Thanks Sime, for ur help. but i need script like one div over another div and some partial text shod apper behind front div. Just like Youtube site.

Comment: @Abhi I've added an answer. On Youtube, are you referring to the button which shows the category, tags and licence ?

Comment: you are absolutely right james, i am looking for that the same functionality.

Comment: Ok, what you could do is have a hidden div (`"display:none;"`) and place it in your page structure as you want it to appear. Then you bind a button in jQuery and call `toggle` on the element (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Thanks James, Il try this and will come back to you. Thankx

Comment: We can take this to a chat if you need further help.

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow, how to come into the chat to chat with you..?

Answer (score 5):

A CSS-only version I just did: http://dabblet.com/gist/3157489

It works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE9+. Show/ hide is functional in IE9, though transitions are missing (gradient fade is emulated using an additional element).

The HTML structure is something like:

```
<div class="info-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showhide">
    <label for="showhide">
            <div class="more">Show more</div>
            <div>Show less</div>
    </label>
    <div class="info">
        <p><!-- text, text, more text --></p>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><div class="aftershadow"></div><![endif]-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.info-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    padding: 0 0 2em 0;
    position: relative;
}
.info {
    max-height: 120px;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5em 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
}
p { margin: 1em; }
.info:after, .aftershadow {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(192,192,192,0), #ccc);
    content: '';
}
.aftershadow {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00cccccc, endColorstr=#ffcccccc);
}
.info-wrapper input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.info-wrapper label {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 1.5em;
    width: 9em;
    height: 1.25em;
    margin:  0 0 0 -2.5em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    font: 700 .67em/1.25em Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info-wrapper label .more { margin: -.1em 0 .35em; transition: 1s; }
.info-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .info {
    max-height: 15em;
}
.info-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked + label .more {
    margin-top: -1.65em;
}
```

The idea is the following: in the HTML structure, you have a checkbox which is hidden, but can be checked/ unchecked by clicking its `label`.

Initially, the info is compacted and the checkbox is unchecked. Clicking on "Show more" (which is inside the `label`) ticks the checkbox and you can now change the style of the elements that are its siblings and come after it in the HTML (the `label` and the `.info` in this case) using the [**`:checked` pseudo-class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/:checked) and the [**the general sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

This is the part that does it:

```
.info-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .info {
    max-height: 15em;
}
.info-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked + label .more {
    margin-top: -1.65em;
}
```

---

Another method that would also work in IE8 would be to use links and their `:focus`/ `:active` pseudo-classes instead of a checkbox and its `:checked` pseudo-class. The disadvantage of this method is that as soon as you click anywhere else in the page, the `.info` gets compacted again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/U7Cyk/

HTML doesn't change much, I'm just replacing the checkbox and the label with two links

```
<div class="info-wrapper">
    <a href="#" tabindex="1" class="more">Show more</a>
    <a href="#" tabindex="1" class="less">Show less</a>
    <div class="info">
        <p><!--stuff, not wasting space here with it--></p>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><div class="aftershadow"></div><![endif]-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is mostly the same. Everything related to `input` & `label` is out and instead there is:

```
.info-wrapper a {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 1.5em;
    width: 9em;
    height: 1.25em;
    margin: -.1em 0 .35em -4.5em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    font: 700 .67em/1.25em Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info-wrapper a:focus { outline: none; }
.info-wrapper .less { 
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    opacity : 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.info-wrapper .more:focus ~ .info, 
.info-wrapper .more:active ~ .info { 
    max-height: 15em;
}
.info-wrapper .less:focus ~ .info, 
.info-wrapper .less:active ~ .info { 
    max-height: 120px;
}
.info-wrapper .more:focus, 
.info-wrapper .more:active {
    opacity: 0;
}
.info-wrapper .more:focus + .less,
.info-wrapper .more:active + .less {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

---

Using jQuery - demo http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/yDfTq/

```
$('.more').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0'}, 1000);
    $('.less').animate({
        'opacity': '1', 
        'z-index': '1'
    }, 1000);
    $('.info').animate({'height': '15em'}, 1000);
});
$('.less').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'opacity': '0',
        'z-index': '-1'
    }, 1000);
    $('.more').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 1000);
    $('.info').animate({'height': '120px'}, 1000);
});
```

​The HTML is the same and the CSS is also mostly the same:

```
.info {
    height: 120px;
    padding: .5em 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
p { margin: 1em; }
.info:after, .aftershadow {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(192,192,192,0), #ccc);
    content: '';
}
.aftershadow {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00cccccc, endColorstr=#ffcccccc);
}
.info-wrapper a {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 1.5em;
    width: 9em;
    height: 1.25em;
    margin: -.1em 0 .35em -4.5em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    font: 700 .67em/1.25em Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info-wrapper a:focus { outline: none; }
.info-wrapper .less { margin-top: -1.5em; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Ana, it works... Thank you.. Thanks to all guys to help me..

Comment: This is a great solution, and was easy to restyle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tags indicates you're willing to use jQuery. The following link explains how this effect can be achieved with slideToggle. The style of the div or other element should be set `display: none;` if you want it to be hidden on the first page load.

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {
   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
});
```

Official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/